# Dynamics problem

Tags: physics, homework

This is school work. I do not want the problem solved for me, but I just want to know what I did wrong with my `ParametricPlot`.

**Question:**

> A material point moves in such a way that its coordinates vary with time as follows $x(t) = -0.130t+13.5t^2 (m)$ and $y(t)=0.530t^3 (m)$. If the force acting on the fifth second equals $F = 16.2N$. Determine the mass of this material point.

**My attempt:**

```
x[t_] := -0.130 t + 13.5 t^2
y[t_] := 0.530 t^3

ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

I tried to make the second derivative have the acceleration equation, but it does not work.

```
ParametricPlot[{Evaluate[D[x[t], {t, 2}]], 
  Evaluate[D[y[t], {t, 2}]]}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT**

From the [corey979](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133776/parametricplot-with-error#comment360927_133776) tip I managed to make the `ParametricPlot`, but the result does not give a value in the fifth second.

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate@{D[x[t], {t, 2}], D[y[t], {t, 2}]}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Is there still something wrong with my problem resolution?

Can I ask this kind of question here because now I want to understand the idea of math?

Comment: `ParametricPlot` takes the first argument (the pair) as a whole. This will work: `ParametricPlot[Evaluate@{D[x[t], {t, 2}], D[y[t], {t, 2}]}, {t, 0, 5}]`.

Comment: How are you computing the acceleration?

Comment: @J.M. Using: `ParametricPlot[Evaluate@{D[x[t], {t, 2}], D[y[t], {t, 2}]}, {t, 0, 5}]`

Comment: Probably, you want `Norm[D[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 2}]] /. t -> 5`.

Comment: @J.M. Does this give me the acceleration in the instant 5 seconds? If so, that's exactly what I need. Grateful.

Comment: @J.M. You could describe what `ParametricPlot[Evaluate@{D[x[t], {t, 2}], D[y[t], {t, 2}]}, {t, 0, 5}]` is representing and what `Norm[D[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 2}]] /. t -> 5` shows. Could you do that as an answer?

Comment: I would try to answer this question, but I also had the same uncertainty as my colleague

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't ignore the mass in your definitions. As you wrote them you are assuming the mass is 1.0, which is not the correct answer.

Try working with the equations

```
x[t_, m_] := -0.130 t + 13.5 m t^2
y[t_, m_] := 0.530 m t^3
```

then the force vector is given by

```
forceV[t_, m_] = {D[x[t, m], {t, 2}], D[y[t, m], {t, 2}]} // Chop
```

> `{27. m, 3.18 m t}`

Since you are given the **magnitude** of force vector at t = 5, you want to work with `Norm[forceV[5, m]]` as J.M. said in his comment; i.e., solve the equation

```
Norm[forceV[5, m]] == 16.2 && m > 0
```